# Animating scrollTop using react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

this should be simple but i think i'm missing something crucial on how Spring works, the documentation is not much of help.

I have a dynamic list, the user can add elements, when that happens i want to use React Spring to animate the scroll to the bottom of the page (identified by `currentBottomY` variable)

i have something like this

```
const mainRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null)

const [y, setY] = useSpring({
    from: { y: mainRef?.current?.scrollTop || 0 },
    onFrame: props => {
       mainRef.current.scrollTop = props.y
    },
})

const onAddRow = () => {
    setY({ y: currentBottomY })
}

return (
    <animated.div ref={mainRef}>
        <List />
    </animated.div>
)
```

I'm getting errors saying i cannot define `from` and `onFrame` in there but in the docs it says otherwise, i really cannot make heads or tails on this, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Matt's pointer i solved the issue and created a reusable hook that accepts the container's ref and scrolls to the bottom when the `scrollToBottom()` function is called.

```
import { useSpring } from 'react-spring'

const useScrollAnimation = (
  containerRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>
): { animate: () => void } => {
  const [, setY] = useSpring(() => ({
    y: 0,
    onFrame: (props: any) => {
      props
    },
  }))

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const current = containerRef?.current
      if (current) {
        const { scrollHeight } = current
        setY({
          config: { duration: 200 },
          y: scrollHeight - current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
          onFrame: (props: any) => (current.scrollTop = props.y),
        })
      }
    }, 0)
  }

  return { scrollToBottom }
}

export default useScrollAnimation
```

Comment: how would you do this with react-spring v9?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the update on a later call, (which is seems like you do), try passing to useSpring hook a function.

```
const [y, setY] = useSpring(() => ({
  from: { y: mainRef?.current?.scrollTop || 0 },
  onFrame: props => {
     mainRef.current.scrollTop = props.y
  },
}));
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me getting to the bottom of it

Comment: how would you do this with react-spring v9?

Comment: @rssfrncs for version 9.x.x instead of `onFrame` use `onChange` and instead of props u need to destructuring object `{ value: { y } }` in this case is y but change if u set other variables